# Save data in mongoDB after scraping the data from a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to save the data that I am scarping from a website with node and mongoDB but I cannot save it in the database. I am able to save the data in the array (bdata) and GET the data to show in my localhost but not save to it.

Would really appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance!

```
    const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express');
const port = 4000;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Phones = require('./models/phones');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/testDatabase");

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const url = 'https://scrapewebsite.com';
const bdata = [];

async function scrapeSite(url) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

        const phones = $('.product-card');
        // loop through products
        phones.each((i, phone) => {
            if ($(phone).find("ins span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount")) {
                price = $(phone).find("ins span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();
            } else if ($(phone).find(".price.font-bold.text-lg.md:text-xl.text-black")) {
                price = $(phone).find(".price.font-bold.text-lg.md:text-xl.text-black").text();
            }
            article_name = $(phone).find(".woocommerce-loop-product__title").text();
            link = $(phone).find("a").attr("href");

            bdata.push({ "article": article_name, "link": link, "price": price });
        });

        //console.log(bdata);
        return;
        // iterate through all pages
        const hasNext = $(".next").text();
        if (hasNext.length > 0) {
            next_page = $(".next").attr('href');
            scrapeSite(next_page);
        }
        console.log(next_page);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

scrapeSite(url);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { bdata: bdata });
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port));
```

And my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PhonesSchema = new Schema({
    article: String,
    link: String,
    price: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Phones', PhonesSchema);
```

Comment: `return` in the middle makes what follows unreachable (from `const hasNext` on...)

Comment: I don't think assigning something to `price` will do anything.  Not a mongoose expert but if it creates an entity that will perform a write, then perhaps `phone.price =`  could be the intended way to update the entity and write back to the database.  Otherwise, I don't see any code that might modify your database here.  I think typically you would also need to make a `model.save(phone)` call somewhere too.  Again, I don't see any of this in your code.

Comment: I managed to save the data with the method .save(), as you mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What made you use the below lines in your code? You are trying to do the same work with inbuilt `middlewares` and also using the separate package `bodyParser` that doesn't make any sense. And hence the problem.

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

`bodyParser` was separated out from the earlier in `version 4.0` but they re-introduced it in the `Express release 4.16.0`. So, for the latest version of `Express` i.e `release >= 4.16.0` you just need to do the following:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and you do not need the below lines in your code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and also get rid of the package `body-parser`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i managed to save the data.
In place of pushing into the array i just saved it with the mongoose method `.save()`

```js
bdata.save({ "article": article_name, "link": link, "price": price });
```

Thank you for the efforts!